# NC JFET switch with only one voltage source

Tags: switches, jfet

The below circuit functions as a NC switch. At Vgs = 0V current flows through the channel of J1 (the JFET). When S is closed J1 will open and
no current flows through the channel anymore. Right now the circuit has two voltage sources in it.

My question: Can we design a JFET switch circuit with only ONE voltage source?

[image]

Comment: A JFET does not behave much like a switch, it is more like a variable resistor. *Can we design a JFET switch with only ONE voltage source?* That question makes no sense. I suggest that you find book which explains the behavior of the JFET and study that. Then maybe come back if you have more detailed questions instead of this "not really understanding the JFET" type question.

Comment: So these websites are wrong? [http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/N-channel-JFET-switch-circuit.php](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/N-channel-JFET-switch-circuit.php)
[http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-5/transistor-switch-jfet](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-5/transistor-switch-jfet)

Comment: Sorry but JFETS are NC switches that Open with Vgs > Vth  unlike enhancement mode MOSFETS that are NO switches.

Comment: Both uses are possible: As a switch:[http://www.electronicshub.org/fet-as-a-switch/#Example_of_N-Channel_JFET_as_a_Switch](http://www.electronicshub.org/fet-as-a-switch/#Example_of_N-Channel_JFET_as_a_Switch) And as a voltage controlled resistor: [http://www.circuitstoday.com/fet-as-a-vvr-voltage-variable-resistor](http://www.circuitstoday.com/fet-as-a-vvr-voltage-variable-resistor)

Comment: @Tony: Sorry you're right. My bad. I meant NC.
With Vth you mean the pinch-off voltage?

Comment: .... yes.....:>)

Comment: These websites are not "wrong" in the sense that it does not work. It does, yes. Is it the most elegant and easy to understand solution ? **No**. It is more like: "I have this JFET and I desparately want to do something with it". The whole idea of using a JFET for this is just silly. The only time I would use a JFET with a LED is to make a (sort of) constant current by using the JFET with Gate and Source shorted. Sane people use an NPN, PNP or MOSFET to switch on/off a led with a voltage.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: Can you please telll me why it's silly? And guide me to information on a more sane way to create a NC switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fICKFb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, you can, but it's a bad idea.  If you pull down the datasheet for the JFET used in the example on learning-about-electronics, you'll find that it's designed to be an RF amplifier.  (Note for example the Iss for zero volts Vgs is maximum 20mA ... ).  By holding Vs a few volts above ground with a small 5.1 V zener (switching to a much higher Vss), you can now have a reasonably high Vds even with a series LED and can pull the gate "well below Vs" to switch off the transistor.  Sometimes you will want a resistor between gate and source (as in this example) ... there is a small finite capacitance between the gate and source, and adding a resistor will help carry away that gate charge.  Even if you leave it out, there will naturally be *some* leakage which will dissipate it naturally.

Comment: It's a bad idea because of the low Iss you mean? The capcitance in the JFET is responsible for the so called "memory' effect of the unit?

Comment: It always depends on "what do you want the part to do?", but if I'm picking a transistor for switching, I'll pick a part characterized for switching, not one characterized as an RF amp.  Consider that the minimum Iss for the part to be in spec was -- what -- 2mA, right?  (I've since closed the datasheet)

Comment: yep. What i need is an NC switch. For low currents (<20mA). What are the choices? JFET, pMOS .. ?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're switching, how you want to control the switch, and the acceptable limits for "on resistance", it's impossible to  speculate how well this would work, but my instinct tells me:  You're getting hung up on the 'normally closed' nature of a depletion FET when some other solution would be better.

Comment: The more 'closed' the better.